# Multivision application - Looking for Someone familiar with Joe Eames Course on MeanStack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am a Pluralsight user and am working through the course and code by Joe Eames on MeanStack where he creates the Multivision application. I am tying to get the Multivision application to work on the latest version of Node and related code. I am Creating a walking Skeleton and just completed, "Creating the Angular Application". Server seems to work fine but when I go to run the client I get a blank screen. Application was working fine up to this point. I did make the change, `bodyParser.urlencoded`, for the versions I am using.

Is it possible that I have a version issue? I am using Webstorm and do have some of the functions highlighted. When I put the curser over the code it says:

> Unresolved variable partialPath

I tried added links to libraries but the underlines did not go away. Do you have any recommendations for troubleshooting this issue? I am new to node, have read some books and taken some of the courses.

```
"dependencies": {
 "body-parser": "^1.14.1",
 "express": "^4.13.3",
 "jade": "^1.11.0",
 "morgan": "^1.6.1",
 "stylus": "^0.52.4"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
 "bower": "^1.7.0"
 }
```